# Unable to download PHP page even web server is running in SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I am unable to view a .php page in a browser after installing apache2 (Version - 2.4.9) and PHP5.5. Instead of the page opening in a browser it just downloads the PHP page.  OS is SUSE Linux.  Why is the .php page geting downloaded instead of being rendered?

Comment: Your apache/php configuration is b0rken. Go through everything and verify that all is as it should be. Don't forget to restart apache as well, so that it loads up mod_php.

Comment: Thanks, uninstalled apache and php5 completely and re-installed it.There is only onw package apache2-mod_php5 in repo, is also got installed. Finally restarted the apache server.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `mod_php` is installed. You can verify with `apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES`; if you do not see `mod_php` then that is why it's not displaying.

If you do have `mod_php` installed then it's most likely an issue with your mime-types; if that's not the issue then make sure you have the `DocumentRoot` defined properly.

Comment: Thanks for update, apache2-mod_php5 is installed for php5. Document Root is set perfectly.

Comment: apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES show's a list of Loaded modules where php5_module is missing. Yes apache module is loaded.Individually apache is tested.

Comment: Everything is removed and installing again. Starting with apache, php and mysql is the process is followed to install

Comment: just apache2 and PHP is installed and apache server is restarted. But same issue unable to open .php page ,it just downloads

Comment: Yes, josten you are right we found the PHP5 module is missing. For this we found the apache config file which describes the list of loaded modules using apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES or httpd/httpd2 -M. The apache config file (/etc/sysconfig/apache2) does not contains PHP5 module in SUSE. Got the list before apache server start and Added the "php5" in it , restarted the server again and listed the modules to verify. Now, it is successfully loaded and can view php file on web browser.

Answer (score 0):

U might be missing a package, try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Should fix the problem

Comment: There is no package with name "libapache2-mod-php5". Searched for rpm but failed to get the package for SUSE

Comment: then use yast2 -i apache2-mod_php5

Comment: Yes, josten you are right we found the PHP5 module is missing. For this we found the apache config file which describes the list of loaded modules using apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES or httpd/httpd2 -M. The apache config file (/etc/sysconfig/apache2) does not contains PHP5 module in SUSE. Got the list before apache server start and Added the "php5" in it , restarted the server again and listed the modules to verify. Now, it is successfully loaded and can view php file on web browser

Comment: you can check the correct answer for this post then :)